# JSMEPath query for nested array not working

Tags: json, azure-cli, jmespath

I have the following JSON structure as a result of an Azure CLI call:

```
az network application-gateway show-backend-health `
         --resource-group $resourceGroup `
         --name $appGatewayName `
```

JSON:

```
{
    "backendAddressPools": [
        {
            "backendAddressPool": {
                "id": "someid",
                "resourceGroup": "rg-myresourcegroup"
            },
            "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
                {
                    "backendHttpSettings": {
                        "id": "someid",
                        "resourceGroup": "rg-myresourcegroup"
                    },
                    "servers": [
                        {
                            "address": "10.96.130.133",
                            "health": "Unhealthy",
                            "healthProbeLog": "Received invalid status code: 503 in the backend server’s HTTP response. As per the health probe configuration, 200-399 is the acceptable status code. Either modify probe configuration or resolve backend issues. To learn more visit - https://aka.ms/StatusCodeMismatch.",
                            "ipConfiguration": {
                                "id": "someid",
                                "resourceGroup": "rg-myresourcegroup"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "address": "10.96.130.134",
                            "health": "Healthy",
                            "healthProbeLog": "OK",
                            "ipConfiguration": {
                                "id": "someid",
                                "resourceGroup": "rg-myresourcegroup"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to query the health state for a specific ip address.

I've tried several approaches but I can't get it working.

- `backendAddressPools[].backendHttpSettingsCollection[].servers[?address='10.96.130.134']`
- `backendAddressPools[].backendHttpSettingsCollection[][?servers.address='10.96.130.134']`

[JSMEPath playground](http://play.jmespath.org/?u=cf6e8d1b-cece-4824-b47b-074ac9896d7a) to view the data

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and what the correct query would be?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It was a syntax error where I needed `==` instead of `=`. This is the resulting query:

```
backendAddressPools[].backendHttpSettingsCollection[].servers[?address=='10.96.130.133'].health | [0]
```